# How to get values from multiple child components in parent using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm building a view that contains a main component, let's call it `ContentComponent`, which serves as a parent for a list of forms, each of them being their own component, like:

- `EvaluationForm`
- `ExperienceForm`
- `ContactForm`
- `HobbiesForm`

What I'm trying to build here is simply a big form that allows me to get all of this information in a single javascript object with a structure like:

```
content: {
   evaluation: {},
   experience: [{}, {}, ...],
   contact: {},
   hobbies: [{}, {}, ...]
}
```

But I'm not sure on how to get the value of each child component from parent, I'm using a `ref` attribute on each component to access the data through `this.$refs`, but would this also work with multiple instances of the same component? Since I have a button under some of these forms to add another instance of the component, so I can have multiple hobbies, and multiple experiences for example, how would I dynamically access those component's values as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-model for each component.

```
<v-evaluation v-model="evaluation" />
<v-experience v-model="experience[0]" />
<v-experience v-model="experience[1]" />
```

in your custom form should have to emit the values on change for example.

Ref: [v-model](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#_3-x-syntax)